# Facebook Graph request with async await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to make a call to my backend (registerSanctumFacebook method) after a facebook Graph request to get user profile info (email), however I'm getting the following error:

```
await is only allowed within async functions
```

Pretty self explanatory, the problem is, I don't know how to make graph start method to work with async-await...

```
const getInfoFromToken = async (token) => {
        const PROFILE_REQUEST_PARAMS = {
          fields: {
            string: 'email',
          },
        };
        const profileRequest = new GraphRequest(
          '/me',
          {token, parameters: PROFILE_REQUEST_PARAMS},
          (error, user) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log('login info has error: ' + error);
            } else {
              //this.setState({userInfo: user});
              console.log('user:', user);
              
            }
          },
        );
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(profileRequest).start();
        let response = await registerSanctumFacebook(user.email,user.id);
        
    };
```

How I call getTokenInfo method:

```
const loginWithFacebook = async () => {
        LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['email']).then(
          login => {
            if (login.isCancelled) {
              console.log('Login cancelled');
            } else {
              AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
                const accessToken = data.accessToken.toString();
                console.log('accessToken',accessToken);
                getInfoFromToken(accessToken);
              });
            }
          },
          error => {
            console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
          },
        );
    };
```

Comment: How are you calling `getInfoFromToken`?

Comment: Just added it to OP, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem statement, I think you should add await on this line

```
    await new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(profileRequest).start();
```

await will only work if the function after await keyword is also async.

or declare registerSanctumFacebook as async